# Ruby Retrieve a Set of String within a String

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing

I have the following issue.

```
phrase = "I love Chrome and firefox, but I don't like ie."

browsers = ["chrome", "firefox", "ie", "opera"]

def little_parser ( str )

  # what's the best way to retrieve all the browsers within phrase?

end
```

If we use the method little_parser( phrase ), it should return

```
["chrome", "firefox", "ie"]
```

If the phrase was:

```
 phrase_2 = "I don't use Opera"
```

If we run little_parser( phrase_2 ), it should return only:

```
["opera"]
```

How do I do that in the simplest way?

Comment: ie can seem a bit vague. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ie

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate through the browsers and use `str.include?` to single out the items which are in the string:

```
def little_parser(str)
  browsers = ["chrome", "firefox", "ie", "opera"]
  browsers.select { |browser| str.include?(browser) }
end
```

Comment: You'd probably want to add `downcase` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
def little_parser(str)
  str.scan(/\w+/).map(&:downcase) & browsers
end
```

Comment: this will not work as per the `OP`s array `phrase`, need to have `downcase` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
phrase = "I love Chrome and firefox, but I don't like ie."

browsers = ["chrome", "firefox", "ie", "opera"]
phrase.scan(/\w+/).select{|i| browsers.include? i.downcase }
#=> ["chrome", "firefox", "ie"]
```